# funcion jquery dentro de ciclo while

Tags: php, jquery, while

Estoy usando una libreria que se llama Jquery Bar Rating para el uso de rate con 5 estrellas, tengo comentarios guardados en una tabla con rate de 1 a 5 estrellas cada uno, y esos comentarios los imprimo con un while:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)):
    echo '<blockquote>
            <select class="seeRate">//Select para mostrar estrellas
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3" selected>3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        <p class="text-justify" style="font-size: 14px;">'.ucfirst($row['note']).'</p>
        <small class="pull-right"><cite><i>'.ucwords(getNameEmp($row['noteBy'])).' - '.$row['noteAt'].'</i></cite></small>';
        echo '</blockquote>';
        echo '<script>$(\'.seeRate\').barrating(\'show\');</script>';
endwhile;
```

Y este es el trigger para las estrellas:

```
$('.seeRate').barrating({
    theme: 'bootstrap-stars',
    readonly: false
  });
});
```

al momento de poner las estrellas dentro del while, solo se muestran bien en el primer comentario, en los demas solo se muestra el dropdown sin estilo, como si no encontrara la librería.

Comment: Intenta sacar esa linea fuera del while: `echo '<script>$(\'.seeRate\').barrating(\'show\');</script>';`

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, tienes que sacar el  `echo '<script>$(\'.seeRate\').barrating(\'show\');</script>';` del bucle while, porque te va a generar la misma etiqueta script tantas veces como resultados haya.

Por otro lado, debes esperar a que se termine de cargar el documento con document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.seeRate').barrating({
    theme: 'bootstrap-stars',
    readonly: false
  });
  $('.seeRate').barrating('show');
});
```